# Javascript Application Key Issue

Tags: parse-platform

I'm using parse to store high scores for an app, the website for my app is displaying the high scores in a leaderboard.
How can I make the javascript application key only have read access?

I want to prevent anyone from grabbing the key and start updating/changing/destroying my data. I am looking for a way to prevent this.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need here is [Class-Level Permission](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#security-class-level-permissions)

1. Browse to your class in the Parse dashboard
2. Click on Security button
3. Untick `Write` to prevent public non-read access to your data

Check the link for more information.